# Negation of the limit of a function involving infinity

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\lvert f(x)\rvert=\infty$.

I am trying to understand the following:
(1) Why exactly is it, when negating the above, that there exists a sequence $x_{n}\to\infty$ such that $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\lvert f(x_{n})\rvert<\infty$?
(2) Given that $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\lvert f(x_{n})\rvert<\infty$, what does it mean that $f$ admits a ''sequential cluster point''?

Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: ad (1): Have you formulated the statement $\lim_{x\to\infty}|f(x)|=\infty$ in terms of sequences? Negating that then gives the statement.

Comment: @johnny10: Thanks for your comment. I have negated the above statement but did not now to ''construct'' the sequence from it.

Comment: The sequential definition is: for all sequences $(x_n)_n$ with $\lim x_n=\infty$ we have $\lim f(x_n)=\infty$. Negating gives the existence of a sequence $(x_n)_n$ with $\lim x_n=\infty$ but $\lim f(x_n)\not=\infty$. Hence there is a subsequence of $(f(x_n))_n$ that is bounded. This gives your statement in (1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$
$\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb N}$

For simplicity in the notations and the proof, I will assume that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = +\infty$ (*i.e.* I remove the absolute value). Conceptually, this does not make a big difference, and I think that you will easily be able to adapt the ideas to the case where we suppose $|f| \to \infty$

(1) Recall the definitions:

$\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = +\infty \Leftrightarrow \forall A \in \R, \exists N \in \R, \forall x \geq N, f(x) \geq A$

If we know that $f$ does not tend to infinity, then we negate the previous formula to obtain:

$\exists A \in \R, \forall N \in \R, \exists x \geq N, f(x) < A $

Informally, it means that exists some threshold $A$ such that no matter how far you go on the real line, you will always be able to find some point $x$ after that, whose image stays below $A$.

Consider the previous formula. You see that for any $N \in \R$, we get the existence of some $x$. In particular, for any $N \in \N \subset \R$, we get the existence of some point $x_N$ such that $x_N \geq N$ and $f(x_N) < A$.

This defines a sequence $(x_N)_{N \in \N}$ which verifies the following properties:

- $x_N \to +\infty$ Indeed, we just said that $x_N \geq N$
- $\sup(f(x_N)) < +\infty$ Indeed, we know that $f(x_N) < A$ so obviously $\sup_{N \in \N} f(x_N) \leq A$.

(2) I assume that a "sequential cluster point" is a point $y \in \R$ such that there exist some sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \N}$ with $f(x_n) \to y$

Here, $f$ does have a sequential cluster point. Indeed, consider the sequence $(f(x_N))_{N \in \N}$ that we previously constructed. This is a positive sequence (at least in your case, because you consider the absolute values), and it has a non-infinite upper bound $A$, hence it is bounded. By the [Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), you can extract a convergent subsequence $(f(x_{\phi(N)}))_{N \in \N}$. This sequence is exactly what we wanted, so $f$ has a sequential cluster point.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. My problem was to ''construct'' the sequence from the negated statement. One minor point: In your second item, we have that $f(x_{N})$ is less than $A$, not $x_{N}$. Thanks again!

Comment: The $x_N$ are more or less "magically spit out of the $\forall N, \exists x$-quantifiers". This is not a very convincing answer, but I think you *understand* why you are allowed to effectively say that the sequence exists using this; dwelling deeper into the formal, logical or philosophical existence of this sequence that only know thanks to some $\exists$ quantifier would take us too far !

Comment: I see... But does the sequential definition of the above statement, once negated, not directly answer the question on the existence of at least one sequence?